# Authorization error at config in DSE

Tags: cassandra, datastax-enterprise

I have just installed a single node of DSE on Ubuntu 16. I have been followubg the DataStax instructions for setting up security using DSE Unified Authentication.

When I log on as the default cassandra user and attempt to set the new super user I get:

```
Unauthorized: Error from server: code=2100 [Unauthorized] message="Anonymous users are not authorized to perform this request"
```

I assume the more experienced users here have come across this before. It does not seem to be well documented though.

Thanks,

Michael.

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted this. The instructions do work if one is using the right YAML file in the right directory. Don't use find to search for yamls! Especially when you are new to linux!!